# Vba Sort.SetRange to python win32com (Excel)

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com, vba

I'd like to translate this macro to python 2.7,

```
Sheets("Données CENTRE").Select
Columns("A:G").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Données CENTRE").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Données CENTRE").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A4644" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Données CENTRE").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B4644" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Données CENTRE").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C4644" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Données CENTRE").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D4644" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Données CENTRE").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:G4644")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

However the last part is giving me a headeach, according to the excel documentation SortRange is suposed to be called on Sort objects only.

but python is telling me : Sort instance has no **call** method

here is how I translated it:

```
ws = wb.Sheets("Données Centre")
ws.Columns("A:G").Select
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear()
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key=ws.Range("A2:A4644"),
                       SortOn=constants.xlSortOnValues,
                       Order=constants.xlAscending,
                       DataOption=constants.xlSortNormal)

ws.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key=ws.Range("B2:B4644"),
                           SortOn=constants.xlSortOnValues,
                           Order=constants.xlAscending,
                           DataOption=constants.xlSortNormal)

ws.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key=ws.Range("C2:C4644"),
                       SortOn=constants.xlSortOnValues,
                       Order=constants.xlAscending,
                       DataOption=constants.xlSortNormal)

ws.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key=ws.Range("D2:D4644"),
                       SortOn=constants.xlSortOnValues,
                       Order=constants.xlAscending,
                       DataOption=constants.xlSortNormal)

ws.Sort(Header=constants.xlYes,
        MatchCase=False,
        Orientation=constants.xlTopToBottom,
        SortMethod=constants.xlPinYin).SetRange(ws.Range("A1:G4644")).Apply()
```

I'm quite lost

Answer (score 0):

Finally found how to :

```
ws.Range("A1:G4644").Sort(Key1=ws.Range("A1:G4644"),
                          Header=constants.xlYes,
                          MatchCase=False,
                          Orientation=constants.xlTopToBottom,
                          SortMethod=constants.xlPinYin)
```